# Api for ASP.NET Web Application (WebForms) Project showing 400

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, webforms

I'm new to the .NET framework and my company doesn't use Core yet, so I'm trying to figure out why my web application api is showing a 400. I had a normal web forms project and added a controller class named **TagController.cs**. My project is on port 44318 and I've tried accessing localhost/44318/api/tag with no luck. I also tried adding a controllers folder with api sub folder and the controller inside it, but to no avail. I've posted images of my project hierarchy and the errors themselves. I have a feeling that the project not having a global.asax could have something to do with it, but there is one in another project. Maybe TagController.cs is pointing to another port? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

**TagController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using ClarityDBWebFormsRedis;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace ClarityDBWebFormsRedis
{
    public class TagController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(string data)        {
            
            return "doge";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have an api config file. There's a web.config file, but this one didn't come with an api.config as it was a web forms project (at least I'm assuming that's why.)  My apologies, I'm coming from a different stack background.

Comment: Is it something I can put in the project folder? Or does it need to come pre-configured?

Comment: is this a web forms project, or a  MVC project? You need (and should) tag this question correctly.  Obviously for a web forms (asp.net web forms application), then you can't use controllers.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Sorry bud! It's a web application. Will edit accordingly.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal that's not fully correct, because you can use Controllers inside a Web Forms project (see my answer). But it can not use the classical MVC Controllers and Views Logic without a MVC project (except implementing this yourself, but that doesn't make much sense)

Comment: Ok, that's fair - but the poster would have to clear this up - and make that clear that this is not standard MVC app - and is standard asp.net + web forms application. I mean, between .net, .net core and the offerings? I'll be the first to admit it can be confusing and hard to keep up. And for those new to this? Well, then I accept that the terminology used  and what correct terms to use can be a challenge here.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal What edit(s) should be made so that the next reader can get it more concisely? I definitely agree the project-type terminology for newcomers (myself) is overwhelming.

Comment: you want to add the tag asp.net-mvc, and thus readers would then know this is a not a asp.net webforms project.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Sure, a clearly asked question with proper tags is appreciated, but still you could have guessed the WebForms project stuff, because me mentioned "I had a normal web forms project (...)" and also the first screenshot of the project structure is clearly not MVC based. Adding the asp.net-mvc tag seems inproper here as he asked for a WebForms project? tags like `webforms` or `.net-framework` would fit better.

Comment: ah ok -  my bad - this is a webforms project - so that tag should be added - and yes I was miss-reading this - so a webforms tag for sure clears this up.

Comment: Updated with the webforms tags for better indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a default (route) configuration in the project, so that it knows what it should do with the ApiControllers, or how the API can be called. This is defined for example in the Global.asax. You can simply put your class `TagController` into a folder called "Controllers".

The Global.asax looks then accordingly e.g. like this:

```cs
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

(...)

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
}
```

An ApiController for example looks like this:

```cs
public class PingController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, AllowAnonymous]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

For normal pages it is enough to create an .Aspx page and then call it in the browser according to the created folder structure. If you use MVC, then this page is created in different files and folders in the project (Views/Home.cshtml, Models/HomeViewModel.cs and Controllers/HomeController.cs).

Comment: You sir, are awesome! Worked like a charm!!